# moving files inside a directory

Tags: python

I have a folder called `parent` that has about 10 files.  I want to be able to copy those 10 files to a new folder, say `new_parent` (The directory will exist already).

I imported `shutil` and tried something like:

```
move('path/to/parent', '/path/to/new_parent')
```

But when I do this, it copies `parent` too, so `new_parent` would look like `new_parent/parent/*10 files*`.

I also tried doing:

```
for file in os.listdir('path/to/parent'):
    move(file, '/path/to/new_parent')
```

But when I do this I get an error saying No such file or directory: 'file1'

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong so I can move the 10 files without the `parent` folder being copied too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
for file in os.listdir('path/to/parent'):
    move('path/to/parent'+os.path.sep+file, '/path/to/new_parent')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it for each file as you are moving in existing directory :-

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(destDir, filename))
```

As per the python move API documentation 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move 
1. If the destination is a directory or a symlink to a directory, then src is moved inside that directory.
2. The destination directory must not already exist.

Comment: It says No such file or directory

Comment: I'll look at this later today or tomorrow.  I am caught up on a couple of things.